# Angular 4 Firebase - Cloud Firestore 'Deeply Nested' vs 'Flatten'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

Curious how to structure the following using "Cloud Firestore (beta)" database

Collections/Entities = '**Menus**', '**Pages**', '**Columns**', '**Sections**', '**Items**'

**Menu** has many **Pages**,
**Page** has many **Columns**,
**Column** has many **Sections**,
**Section** has many **Items**.
Would I be correct in structuring this where ...

- **Page** doc has ***menuId***
- **Column** doc has ***pageId***
- **Section** doc has ***columnId***
- **Item** doc has ***sectionId***

So for example I would retrieve all menu-pages with..

```
this.afs.collection('pages', ref => ref.where('menuId', '==', menuId));
```

all page-columns with..

```
this.afs.collection('columns', ref => ref.where('pageId', '==', pageId));
```

Or should I structure this as subcollections?

Comment: which you using real time database or firestore?

Comment: "Cloud firestore (beta)" :)

Comment: but you are pointed to wrong doc. check this doc for firestore [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NoSQL, your first question is always "How will I query this data from my app?". You have a series of One-to-Many relationships (i.e, page to column), which leads to two main patterns.

1. Hierarchy (parent-child). If the columns are always queried via the parent doc, nest a subcollection. Then you can grab the collection anytime you have a reference to the parent doc`pageRef.collection('columns')`.
2. Denormalized (sibling). But what if you need to query columns across multiple pages? In that case, you might want to use a root or higher level collection, saving a reference or id to it's sibling-level page. Then you can make queries like `afs.collection('columns', ref => ref.where('color', '==', 'orange'))`, allowing you to query columns without recursing the database tree to find all the subcollections.